# Why is NSTimer not working in this code?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to get variations of this code to run, but `countItems()` never prints out the `NSLog`. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
func someFunction() {

    var fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    someTimer = NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: 120, target: self, selector: "countItems", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func countItems() {

    NSLog("countItems")

    //Perform some code here...     
}
```

Comment: Please, read the docs. Search Stack Overflow. Search google. Save bandwidth! Don't waste everyone's time like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading the docs! It's all right there. You have created the timer but you have never *scheduled it* on a run loop. So it does nothing. The docs clearly say:

> You *must* add the new timer to a run loop, using `addTimer:forMode:`.

Well, you don't.

You might be happier like this:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
    120, target: self, selector: "countItems", userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add fire():

```
func someFunction() {

  var fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
  someTimer = NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: 120, target: self, selector: "countItems", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  someTimer.fire()
}
```

Or it wont start: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire)

Comment: This will fire the timer *immediately* and only *once*, which is probably not what OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but not the solution I was looking for.